# How do I output an error in my VB.Net code?

Tags: vb.net

I need help with completing this pre-release. An image of the pre-release can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvTvB.jpg).

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Day(13) As Date
    Dim licenceNumber(19) As String
    Dim carPark(19) As Integer
    Dim name As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 19
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter name")
        name = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number plate")
        i = i + 1
        licenceNumber(19) = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a day from 1 to 14 inclusive. 1 being the earliest date and 14 being the latest date")
        i = i + 1
        If Console.ReadLine > 14 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your date is out of range")
        End If
    Next i
    i = i + 1
End Sub
```

I dont know what to write after telling the visitors to pick a number from 1 to 14.
I want to show an error and I don't know how. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you covered CLASSES (Object Oriented Programming) yet? You need to track up to 20 spaces, PER DAY. What you've got isn't going to be able to handle this...

Comment: I was told a couple of times to use classes but classes are quite challenging. I'll try and use them. Thanks.